# How does the hadoop fix the number of mappers or Input splits when mapreduce task is done over multiple input files?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, hadoop2

I've four input files (CSV) of sizes 453MB, 449MB, 646MB and 349MB. All these constitute to a total size of 1.85GB. 
HDFS block size is 128MB.
Record size is very less as there are hardly 20 fields.
After the completion of mapreduce task, I can observe that 16 mappers have been used for the input files I've provided:

[image]

I would like to know how hadoop determined the number of mappers or input splits for multiple input files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each file undergoes splitting (based on the split size) individually unless you are using [`CombileFileInputFormat`](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.0.0-alpha2/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/lib/CombineFileInputFormat.html).

Assuming the `mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.minsize` and `mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.maxsize` properties are at their default. Then the split size will be approximately equal to the  `dfs.blocksize`.

So, in this case

```
File 1: 453MB = 4 splits 
File 2: 449MB = 4 splits
File 3: 646MB = 5 splits (boundary being very close ~640MB)
File 4: 349MB = 3 splits
```

Total of 16 splits. And with one mapper per split, a total of 16 mappers will be spawned. Also refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42431546/7303447) for split size computation formula.

**UPDATE:** Although File 3 has 6 blocks, the 6th block will remain to be part of the 5th split. This is decided by the `SPLIT_SLOP` factor, which is 1.1 by default (last block to overflow by 10%).

Comment: By using the command "hadoop fsck <hdfs-file-location> -files -blocks", I came to know that file 3 has generated 6 blocks.

Comment: @SatishVarada there is some slack when assigning splits, you don't really want to run a mapper for a few bytes of data in a dangling block.

Comment: @ThomasJungblut, I agree with your point. But as per my knowledge, input-split size exceeds the block size only to get the incomplete record present in the block. Did I understood anything wrong here?

Comment: @SatishVarada, MapReduce tries to accomodate these additional few bytes into a split during splitting. Creating a mapper for 6 MB is very expensive.

Comment: @franklinsijo, I agree with your point. **Creating a mapper for 6 MB is very expensive**. As it is only a 6MB block, no need to create an additional mapper. Then, what should be the min block size so that an additional mapper is created?

Comment: When it exceeds the `SPLIT_SLOP`. Default slop factor is 1.1 which allows last block to overflow by 10%.

Comment: @franklinsijo, perfect... Now I understood the Input splitting mechanism. **SPLIT_SLOP** makes lot of sense. As the left over(646-128*4=134) 134MB / 128MB =1.04 < 1.1, no new input split is needed. So, it ended up with 5(4+1) input splits!!!

Answer (score 0):

The number of maps is usually driven by the number of HDFS blocks in the input files. Number of Mappers is calculated on the number of splits, however if the files are less than the split size then each file will correspond to one mapper.

For each input file, with the file length, the block size , hadoop calculates the split size as max(minSize, min(maxSize, blockSize)) where maxSize corresponds to mapred.max.split.size and minSize is mapred.min.split.size.

No. of mappers= each file size /inputSplitSize

Here is reference about number of Mappers and reducers on apache wiki http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HowManyMapsAndReduces

Comment: Files are not merged before splitting. So, it is not total size divided by split size.